# How to change Marker/data point color on Tap for Flutter Line Chart

Tags: flutter, linechart, syncfusion-chart

[Line chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgRjn.png)

Please I don't know how I can make a Flutter chart responsive on Tap. In the attached image, one of the points have been selected and the color changed. I want to know what widget can be used in order to change the color of a point/marker in a Flutter line chart whenever I tap on that point. Currently I'm using SfSparkLineChart widget.

Secondly, the chart does not start from 0 value but from the minimum value in the given dataset. How can I make the chart jump to give space for the zero value and other less values whenever the minimum value is greater that zero

Comment: Looking through the documentation, the closest thing I see for selection is the Trackball functionality: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/sparkcharts/trackball. I'm not seeing anything for modifying the axis range.

Comment: Yes. But it's there a way I can change the inner color of the circles on Tap. Or is there any other flutter chart that can be used to perform that?